# Negate condition of an if-statement

Tags: scala

If I want to do something like:

```
if (!(condition)) { }
```

What is the equivalent expression in Scala?
Does it looks like?

```
if (not(condition)) { }
```

For example, in C++, I can do:

```
bool condition = (x > 0)
if(!condition){ printf("x is not larger than zero") }
```

EDIT: I have realized that Scala can definitely do the same thing as I asked. Please go ahead and try it.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I am asking `if(!condition){}`. The condition can be anything. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffHu What is "anything"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov For example, in C++, I can do: 
`bool condition = (x > 0)`
`if(!condition){ printf("x is not larger than zero") }`

Comment: You can do the same in Scala.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Scala, you can check `if` two operands are equal (`==`) or not (`!=`) and it returns true if the condition is met, false if not (`else`).

```
if(x!=0) {
    // if x is not equal to 0
} else {
    // if x is equal to 0
}
```

By itself, `!` is called the **Logical NOT Operator**.

Use it to reverse the logical state of its operand.

If a condition is true then Logical NOT operator will make it false.

```
if(!(condition)) {
    // condition not met
} else {
    // condition met
}
```

Where `!(condition)` can be

- any (logical) expression

  - eg: `x==0`

    - -> `!(x==0)`
- any (boolean like) value

  - eg: `someStr.isEmpty`

    - -> `!someStr.isEmpty`

      - no need redundant parentheses

Comment: Thanks! How about I only want to do (!condition) ?

Comment: @JeffHu That works too, when your condition is e.g. a call to a boolean function.

Answer (score 4):

`if (! condition) { doSomething() }`

`condition` in the above `if` expression can be any expression which evaluates to `Boolean`

for example

```
val condition = 5 % 2 == 0

if (! condition) { println("5 is odd") }
```

`!=` is equivalent to `negation of ==`

```
if (x != 0) <expression> else <another expression>
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> if (true) 1
res2: AnyVal = 1

scala> if (true) 1
res3: AnyVal = 1

scala> if (true) 1 else 2
res4: Int = 1
```